# Iterate over a list enabling and disabling display:block

Tags: angular

Im trying to build a gallery in angular where the user can click on an image and it will select the current n+1 and add an active class whilst making all others inactive and hidden, Im trying to use renderer2 for it but im not so sure how to proceed

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, ViewChild, QueryList, ViewChildren, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
    selector: 'gallery',
    templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.scss'],
    })
    export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() alblum: any[];

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    @ViewChildren("pRef") private pRef: QueryList<ElementRef>;  

    changePhoto2(album: any[]) {
        console.log("album "+album)
        console.log("album.length "+album.length)  
        this.pRef.forEach((image: ElementRef) => {
            console.log(this.renderer.nextSibling(image.nativeElement))  
        });    
    }  



    }
```

The html so far is

```
  <div 
    #pRef
    class="albums galleryImage"
    *ngFor="let h of alblum;  let x=index" 
    [ngClass]=" ( currentActive() == x ) ? 'active' : 'disabled' "
    [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ h +')'}"
    [attr.data-img]="x"
    (click)="changePhoto2(alblum)">
  </div>
```

Comment: Why would you use Renderer2 to do this? Just use binding. Actually, you're **already** using binding: `[ngClass]=" ( currentActive() == x ) ? 'active' : 'disabled' "`. All you need now is to implement the currentActive() method so that it returns the index of the album that should be active.

Comment: I actually had this working before, its basically nested within a parent ngfor but I was having issues as this was using a global variable to change the image so when you click on one of the child galleries it toggled all other galleries in the parent ngfor, I opened an issue for it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647496/parent-ngfor-has-a-child-ngfor-with-a-gallery-clicking-the-image-affects-all/59665553#59665553 , at the moment Im trying to find a way to rewrite it and I have moved it into a child component which is simply fed the array of images

Comment: OK. That doesn't change anything: you still should use binding, and not mess with Renderer2.

Comment: Binding changes all other galleries man, any tips for that ?

Comment: If you want help on that, edit your question, explain what you want to achieve, post what you have tried, explain what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. A complete minimal example reproducing the issue, on StackBlitz would tremendously help understanding the problem and would allow to easily reproduce it and fix it, too.

Comment: I simply need to be able to click on an image and for the next image in the array to be activated/set to display - this needs to work within the context of a child ngfor loop so that none of the other galleries change the active image.

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't very clear to me. What I understand: you have a model with N galleries. Each gallery has X images. Then what? What should be displayed in the page? What should the user do? What should happen? Read my previous comment again, edit your question, and provide all the necessary details, along with the code.

Comment: No worries dude I guess you dont understand.

Comment: Its pretty simple: Change image on click, keep it isolated to only the current instance of ngfor, change image to the next one in the list, reach end of array.length and iterate backwards

Comment: OK, so, if I understand correctly, your page initially displays all the pictures of all the galleries, and when you click on a picture of gallery 2, you would like to only display that picture in the page. And when you click on the picture, it should display the next picture of the same gallery. When you reach the last picture (at index X - 1) of the gallery, clicking on the picture should then show the previous one (at index X - 2), and again and again until the first picture of the gallery is reached. Is that correct? And of course: *where is the code you tried*?

Comment: Anyway, if what I understood is correct, you need to have 3 state variables in your component: one to contain the selected gallery (so that you only iterate on the pictures of that gallery), one for the index of the displayed picture (to only display that picture), and one to contain the direction of the iteration (to know if a click should display the picture at the next index, or at the previous index). You posted no code, so I won't post any either.